# Extract text between quotes and move to next cell/row vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have different text in column A between quotes; i would like to extract the text between quotes and move the text to the next column (B) without the quotes.

```
Sub ExtractText() 
    Dim iPos1 As Integer 
    Dim iPos2 As Integer 

    iPos1 = InStr(Sheet1.Cells(2, 1), """ ") 
    iPos2 = InStr(Sheet1.Cells(2, 1), " """) 

    Sheet1.Cells(2, 2) = Trim(Mid(Sheet1.Cells(2, 1), iPos1 + 1, iPos2 - iPos1 - 1)) 
End Sub
```

Comment: Use Split().  split on the quotes then return the second item in the array.

Comment: Column 24 ain't column B either. Also not any question is asked really...

Comment: Thanks BigBen. Correct, this is the base code I have been editing to try and get the text to extract between quotes. The work in progress code has quotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `Split` has already been already proposed, here is an example:

```
Sub ExtractText()
    Dim splitText As Variant
    splitText = Split(Sheet1.Cells(2, 1).Value, """")

    Sheet1.Cells(2, 2).Value = Trim$(splitText(1))
End Sub
```

An example:
[image]

Comment: To take this further, how can I add a range on this to execute across all cells in column A? Some cells dont have quotes, some do. 

Will i need a check command?

Comment: @B.Cole `Sheet1.Cells(2, 2).Value = Trim$(splitText(IIF(UBound(splitText)>0,1,0)))`

Comment: @ScottCraner I can't get that to apply across all of column A?

Comment: @B.Cole that was only to deal with the ones missing the `""`  as to the whole column you will need to loop through the cells in the column.  There are many examples how to do that.

Comment: @ScottCraner I am searching like a mad man, but I just cant seem to find anything that I can mesh with the split command?

Answer (score 2):

Just an FYI a simple function can do this:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("""",A2)),TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"""",REPT(" ",999)),999,999)),A2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Building on the need to:

- Use VBA
- Loop column A
- Only extract when double quotes are returned (more than 1)

Try the code below:

```
Sub Test()

Dim arr As Variant
Dim lr As Long, x As Long

With Sheet1 'Change according to your sheet's CodeName
    lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    arr = .Range("A1:A" & lr).Value
    For x = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        If InStr(1, arr(x, 1), """") < InStrRev(arr(x, 1), """") Then
            .Cells(x, 2) = Trim(Split(arr(x, 1), """")(1))
        Else
            '.Cells(x, 2) = arr(x, 1) ': Remove the single quote if need be
        End If
    Next x
End With

End Sub
```